# cannot view the layout with activity pause timeout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have run my Activity -> `on create(with setContentView layout)`-> run a `asyncTask`(in asynctask: request Database with php and SQL-> get the response -> set the textView with the SQL result)
i use `Log.e` to Track the progress, there are no error in the class until the asyncTask is end but the emulator didn't change its view to the layout

my logcat:

```
08-26 06:29:49.644    1232-1289/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
08-26 06:29:49.859    1232-1522/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{390da99d u0 com.primo.blindpig_managerv1/com.primo.blindpig_managerv1.order} at 3 of 8 (after Window{3730a638 u0 com.primo.blindpig_managerv1/com.primo.blindpig_managerv1.index})
08-26 06:29:49.868    1232-2073/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{1d919e3 u0 com.primo.blindpig_managerv1/com.primo.blindpig_managerv1.order} at 3 of 9 (before Window{390da99d u0 com.primo.blindpig_managerv1/com.primo.blindpig_managerv1.order})
08-26 06:29:49.959    2572-2589/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 06:29:49.959    2572-2589/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4811340, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-26 06:29:50.113    2572-2595/? V/Checking data﹕ {"orders":[{"invoice_number":"5","order_number":"150825214234","customer_id":"39","applecider":"580","blackcurrant":"0","mankahoney":"0","kiwifruit":"0","pearlemon":"0","order_at":"2015-08-26 05:42:51","amount":"174000","remark":"","userstatus":"outlet","name":"tgv","phone":"588","email":"fcd@dd.cc","status":0}],"success":1}
08-26 06:29:50.113    2572-2595/? D/Create Response﹕ {"orders":[{"invoice_number":"5","order_number":"150825214234","customer_id":"39","applecider":"580","blackcurrant":"0","mankahoney":"0","kiwifruit":"0","pearlemon":"0","order_at":"2015-08-26 05:42:51","amount":"174000","remark":"","userstatus":"outlet","name":"tgv","phone":"588","email":"fcd@dd.cc","status":0}],"success":1}
08-26 06:29:50.123    2572-2589/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 06:29:50.123    2572-2589/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4812800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-26 06:29:50.672    1232-1250/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{245be861 u0 com.primo.blindpig_managerv1/.order t11 f}
08-26 06:29:55.187    2572-2572/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 318 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-26 06:29:55.598    1232-1472/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@36709a0c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@19b6a29b
```

is there any possible reason causes error?
my activtiy have many variables findbyid to setText, is it cause the error?

```
    class callcustomerorder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        String count = countingPage.toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", count));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_customer_order,
                "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                orders = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ORDERS);

                    invoice_numebr = c.getString("invoice_number"); 
                }

                // closing this screen
```

> ```
>                finish();  <<<<<　here  cause the activity shut down
> ```

```
            } else if (success == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to connect next order", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

private void settingStatusTextView() {
    switch (intstatus) {
        case 0:
            status.setText("A");
            break;
        case 1:
            status.setText("B");
            break;
        case 2:
            status.setText("C");
            break;
        case 3:
            status.setText("D");
            break;
    }
}
```

i think so.. because it is really really long... to set TextView..

Comment: This is not the error. All are warnings. Show your code or your logcat

Comment: Your app has no error...but it might be lagging bcoz **The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.** as mentioned in the logcat...if you are doing any heavy amount of work then do that in child thread...also try to reduce the view hiearchy as far as possible

Comment: #1 here is the logcat  after start intent to the next class.   
#2 thank you for your advice, is there any method to reduce the work on settext  and asynctask?

Comment: if you can share the xml/view along with the code where you are setting and asynctask...it might help

Comment: if possible can you call settingStatusTextView, StoreNameAndQty and, checkView all this method inside postExecute method and don't use runnable thread

Comment: handle ui related code inside postExecute(String jsonData)

Comment: i put all the UI (including setText and findViewbyid) in postExecute. it still get the warning (Window already focused) and (Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord). no change in the view

Comment: ........finally  i found finish()  in asyncTask that causes the Activity shut down.   i removed it and it works